# IllegalArgumentException: Must have a local (user) JID set. Either you didn't configure one or you where not connected at least once

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Получаю `IllegalArgumentException: Must have a local (user) JID set. Either you didn't configure one or you where not connected at least once` при использовании `UserSearchManager` в `Smack`. Подскажите, что может быть не так? Я пробовала указывать username (user2@192.168.1.176/Irynas-MacBook-Air) с ресурсами, но получала ту же ошибку.

```
     public void getRegisteredUser() {

 String username = "user2@192.168.1.176";

 Log.e("Connection == null", String.valueOf(connection==null));
 UserSearchManager manager = new UserSearchManager(connection);


            try {
                String searchFormString = "search." + connection.getServiceName();
                Log.d("***", "SearchForm: " + searchFormString);
                Form searchForm = manager.getSearchForm(searchFormString);
                Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();

                UserSearch userSearch = new UserSearch();
                answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
                answerForm.setAnswer("search", username);

                ReportedData results = userSearch.sendSearchForm(connection, answerForm, searchFormString);
                if (results != null) {
                    List<ReportedData.Row> rows = results.getRows();
                    for (ReportedData.Row row : rows) {
                        Log.e("Row in reported data: ", String.valueOf(row));

                        ArrayList<String> arrayListContact = new ArrayList<>();
                        ArrayList<String> openfire = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (String str1 : arrayListContact) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < openfire.size(); i++) {
                                String opencontact = openfire.get(i);    
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("***", "No result found");
                }
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поняла в чем проблема, я пыталась искать юзеров, до того, как пользователь был залогинен. Когда запускаю этот код, сразу после того, как юзер залогинился, то все работает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий пример, например, для удаления

```
String jid = name + "@192.168.0.1";
Roster roster = getInstance().getRoster();
RosterEntry rosterEntry = roster.getEntry(jid);
roster.removeEntry(roster.getEntry(jid));
```

Абсолютно точно в адресе не указываю ресурсов. В документации указано также так:

> the XMPP address of the user (eg "jsmith@example.com"). The address
>   could be in any valid format (e.g. "domain/resource", "user@domain" or
>   "user@domain/resource").